# Mongoose Schema: Using nested arrays to store data that will be queried for

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am  using mongodb and mongoose to store data for a group of students.

They attend a camp session once or twice a year in grades K & 1, and I mainly want to keep track of the  skills that the students achieved mastery in, and the  dates that they achieved it, as well as some personal, session-specific data.

Here is my schema:

```
var location = ["DJ", "MLK"];
var days = ["MoWe", "TuTh"];
var grades = ["K", "First"];
var skills = ["FK", "BC", "BK", "IK", "PS", "SLF", "RBC", "RBK", "RIK", "FS", "BS"];
var achievements = ["Red", "Yellow", "Green"];


var studentSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  sessionInfo: [{
    sessionName: String,
    location: {type: String, enum: locations},
    instructor: String,
    class: {school: String, teacher: String},
    grade: {type: String, enum : grades},
    age: {type: Number},
    days: {type: String, enum : days}}],
    skills: [{skill: {type: String, enum: skills}, date: Date}],
    absences: [{date:  Date, reason: String}],
    achievements: [{achievement: {type: String, enum: achievements}}],
    notes: [{instructorName: String, note: String}]
});
```

Because the students will at most attend 3 or 4 sessions, I thought it made sense to store the session info in it's  own array than to try to store each student-session in it's own separate document.

My question is whether or not this will significantly impact the response time for querying the database if  I am going to be regularly querying for students based on skills attained, grade, school, and location.

Note that none of the arrays within the session info will be growing without bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mongodb stores indexes in RAM, if the size of your collection is large then performance can be lower in case of creating separate collection for sessionInfo where every session will have its own already indexed ObjectId (Assuming total number of sessions for all the students will be very large).

It is generally faster to query indexed ObjectId than querying for a primary key in an Array of objects. But as you said sessionInfo array won't be having more than 3 to 4 records, it is better to keep sessionInfo an array. Also you can create index on a particular property of session object.